# Revert Git pull

Tags: git

I have a Git commit picture that looks like this:

```
(master)(origin/master)<---o
                           | \
                           |  \
                           |  |
                           |  |
                           |  o--->commit D
                           |  |
                           |  |
                           |  o--->commit C
                           |  |
                           |  |
               commit B<---o  |
                           |  |
                           | /
               commit A<---o/
                           |
                           |
                    earlier commits
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
(master)(origin/master)<---o--->commit B
                           |
                           |
                           o--->commit A
                           |
                           |
                    earlier commits
```

Can anyone help? I want to forfeit commits C and D. And can anyone tell me what is the better way to learn Git? It seems that I am often restrained by Git rather than being able to harness its power. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to change both Master and Origin/master ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to forfeit commits C and D.

You just need to `git reset --hard HEAD~` to move back to the previous commit. `--hard` will discard all changes and give you a clean working directory.

> And can anyone tell me what is the better way to learn Git?

Keep using it. Experience is the best teacher.

Comment: Is there any number I should put after `HEAD~`?

Comment: No, just `git reset --hard HEAD~` as I've typed it

Comment: The local side looks good now after using your command. But how about the origin side?

Comment: If you want to discard the commits from your remote, you need to `git push -f` after performing the reset. Note that anybody else can reintroduce those commits by pushing. You need to coordinate with everybody else to remove those commits, if other people are using the repository.

Comment: Thx. It works. I have the feeling that learning Git using an on-demand cookbook recipe style is not going to help me understand Git much. Is there anything I can read to understand the idea/philosophy behind Git and its various commands?